# How to make decoding generic function in Swift

Tags: swift, function, methods, alamofire, decoding

I have to get some json from Alamofire and save them into different structs I made, but I can't find the way to make just one method for all the requests I need to make. Here's my method

```
func fetchData(url: String, parameters: [String : Any], finished: @escaping (EmployeeCompositionApp) -> Void)  {

    Alamofire.request(url,
                      method: .post,
                      parameters: parameters).responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in

        guard response.result.error == nil else {
            print("Error en la petición a Alamofire:\n \(String(describing: response.result.error))")
            return
        }
        guard let json = response.result.value as? [String : Any] else {
            if let error = response.result.error {
                print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            return
        }
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let rawData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: [])
            let dataObject = try decoder.decode(EmployeeCompositionApp.self, from: rawData)
            finished(dataObject)

        } catch let error {

            print("Error")
                        }
    })
}
```

But when I try to replace `EmployeeCompositionApp` for `Any` or any other generic type so I can use it with other objects, Xcode says

`Cannot invoke 'decode' with an argument list of type '(Any, from: Data)'`

How could I do it?

Comment: You should use a type that either conform to `<T:Codable>` or `<T:Decodable>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need the type to be `Decodable`:

```
func fetchData<T: Decodable>(url: String, parameters: [String : Any], finished: @escaping (T) -> Void) {
```

and then

```
let dataObject = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: rawData)
```

Also note that it does not make sense to use `Alamofire` to convert JSON data to a dictionary and then encode it back to `Data` so that you could use `JSONDecoder()`. Use `.responseData` instead of `.responseJSON`:

```
func fetchData<T: Decodable>(url: String, parameters: [String : Any], finished: @escaping (T) -> Void)  {
    Alamofire.request(
        url,
        method: .post,
        parameters: parameters
    ).responseData { response in
        guard
           response.result.error == nil,
           let data = response.result.value
        else {
           print("Error en la petición a Alamofire:\n \(String(describing: response.result.error))")
           return
        }

        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let dataObject = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
            finished(dataObject)
        } catch {
            print("Error")
        }
    }
}
```

Also note that when an error happens, you should give that information back to the caller somehow, don't just print the error.

Comment: great thanks! this solved my problem